# Can Fiddler download Web Server Log files?

Tags: httpresponse, fiddler

I have to manually upload a file with the browser using a `https://` destination.
Now I also need to get the logs from that HTTP server.

I tried around already with Fiddler2 and I do get logs but only from my client.
Is there a way to get the response logs from the HTTP server?
(I need to do this because the party that runs the server would have to setup a VPN tunnel to log my uploads and they do not want to do that)

Comment: When you say "Response logs" what exactly do you mean? The Web Server log file? Or something else?

Comment: Hello EricLaw, yes I mean the web server log file. The HTTP Log files the server writes when it gets the file I upload. Is it possible to get those with Fiddler2? Best regards, Peter

Comment: Web Servers typically are configured not to allow clients to download their log files for security reasons. You could probably write an ASPX or PHP page that would leak out the log file to you, but this would present a security risk unless properly authenticated/secured.

Comment: Hello Eric, thank you for your answer. It's been a long time since I did PHP stuff, I think I could not pull that off and I also don't want to cause security risks on our partner's server. I will talk to them again and they need to do whatever it takes to get me the logfiles. Thank you and best regards, Peter